# How to find specific dates when specific versions of Google Play Services are released?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Why am I asking this as a developer question? Because a user is unlikely to care, but there are cases when a developer needs to know exactly when versions of Google Play Services came out in the past--like this one.

I'm examining a bug that appeared to spike suddenly in our Crashlytics reports since about October 5th. We've been having a difficult time trying to explain why there would be a huge jump in error occurrences when the app code hasn't changed and usage/app version/OS level stats are stable for the same time period. One theory is that they updated to a new version of Google Play Services. To verify that, we would need to know exactly what version of Google Play Services rolled out when. I am aware that they do staged rollouts--not every phone updates the same day--but it would be good to know the first day it's available. I can find APK hosting sites and what day they add a Google Play Services APK, but that's hardly official.

And yes, I'm aware that if I had logged the device's version of Google Play Services in Crashlytics, then I would have that data available now. Good to know for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [history of Google Play releases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play_Services#Version_history) starting from Version 1.0 up to the current 9.4 with their respective dates:

```
Version 1.0 was released on September 26, 2012.[14]
Version 3.1 was released on May 16, 2013.[15]
Version 3.2 was released on August 20, 2013.[16]
Version 4.0 was released on October 31, 2013.[17]
Version 4.1 was released on January 9, 2014.[18]
Version 4.2 was released on February 3, 2014.[19]
Version 4.3 was released on March 17, 2014.[20]
Version 4.4 was released on May 7, 2014.[21]
Version 5.0 was released on June 25, 2014 with rollout finishing on July 2, 2014.[22][23]
Version 6.1 was released on September 16, 2014.[24]
Version 6.5 was released on November 17, 2014.[25]
Version 7.0 was released on March 2, 2015.[26]
Version 8.0 was released on August 28, 2015.[27]
Version 8.3 was released on November 5, 2015.[28]
Version 8.4 was released on December 18, 2015.[29]
Version 8.7 was released on February 21, 2016.
Version 8.9 was released on April 14, 2016.
Version 9.0 was released on May 4, 2016.
Version 9.2 was released on June, 2016.
Version 9.4 was released on August 1, 2016.
```

Comment: That's terrific! But where did you get it from? I'm really looking for 9.6 and 9.8 (although it seems 9.8 may be out unofficially, not officially)

Comment: There seems to be no specific day specified for 9.6 release aside from the September month that's been provided. There's a 3rd party website called [APK mirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-9-6-78-release/) that may give you an idea but I don't know if it's reliable. We can only know so much.

Comment: What was the source for the data in your answer?

Comment: click on 'history of Google Play releases', I attached a link

Answer (score 0):

Check out the release notes at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

It doesn't seem to identify every single version but there is at least some info about the major revisions.

Comment: Yes. That was the first resource I checked. It only gives the month of release--I need the exact day, which is why I asked for how to find specific dates when releases came out. Thanks anyway.